# Categories and subcategories Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongoose, handlebars.js, categories

I have categories and subcategories, and I'm trying to show them, but it doesn't work. I'm using express, mongoose, and Handlebars.

My model structure is like this:

```
name: String,
parentID: {type: String, default: null},
icon: {type: String, default: null},
slug: {type: String, unique: true},
```

I made a global variable to show categories, like that:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    Category.find({parentID: null}, function(err, categories){
        res.locals.categories = categories; 
        next();
    });
});
```

After I'm trying to show as a partial:

```
{{#each categories}}
...
{{/each}}
```

I tried to make a helper, but it doesn't work

```
helpers: {
    subcategories: function (id) {
        Category.find({parentID: id}, function(err, subcategory){
            return subcategory;
        });
    },
},
```

I think that one of the problems is as Handlebars can only work with synchronous helpers, but I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: if `parentID` is a refence then you have to have `parentID: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'model_name' }`

Comment: I don't have a separate collection for subcategories. This works like that
http://sqllessons.com/categories.html

Comment: For these kind of database schema, don't choose mongodb. Choose any RDBMS database

Comment: Hmm, I'll try to make a separate collection.

Comment: Even if you make separate collection , it wont give you performance. Because nature of your data is for RDBMS so don't try to mold it to noSQL strucutre

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    Category.find({parentID: $ne : null}, function(err, categories){
        res.locals.categories = categories; 
        next();
    });
});
```

You must use $ne if you want to return a null value